# Tensorflow serving variable file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm about to do tensorflow serving.

pb file and variable folder are created.
but No file was created under the variable folder.

like this

```
    └── variables
        ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
        └── variables.index
```

After further experimentation, I found that the file only occurs when output is output to tf.Variable.

for example

> 1) z = tf.Variable(3,dtype=tf.float32)
>
> 2) z = tf.constant(3,dtype=tf.float32)

## 1) is created the file but 2) is not created file

z is output variable

```
signature_def_map= {
                "serving_default": tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.predict_signature_def( 
                    inputs= {"egg": x, "bacon":y},
                    outputs= {"spam": z})
            })
```

Is it right that I found out?

The above explanation is a test result as a simple example.

This is what I really want to do

```
sIdSorted = tf.gather(sId, indices[::-1])[0:5]
sess=tf.Session()
print sess.run(sIdSorted,feed_dict={userLat:37.12,userLon:127.2})
```

As a result of printing, it was output as follows.
['s7' 's1' 's2' 's3' 's4']

However, in this way, nothing is displayed in the variable folder.....

So I tried to output to tf.variable.

```
sIdSorted = tf.Variable(tf.gather(sId, indices[::-1])[0:5])
```

but This will output an error to the following.

```
initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("strided_slice_1:0", dtype=string)
```

so I tried it as follows.

```
sIdSorted = tf.Variable(tf.constant(tf.gather(sId, indices[::-1])[0:5],shape=[5]))
```

but This will output an error to the following.

```
List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

I need your help. Thank you for reading.

**tensorflow version :1.3.0 python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

That is correct: only `tf.Variable`s result in variable files being exported. Those files contain the actual values of the variables. The graph structure itself is stored in the `saved_model.pb`. That's where your gather (and any other ops) are. You should be able to serve the model.